# MongoDB $addFields, add boolean field based on condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have a list of places documents which have opening times, which is an object detailed below:

```
  "openingTimes": {
    "Wednesday": [ // array of shifts
      {
        "startTime": { "hour": 1, "minute": 0 }, // shift starts
        "endTime": { "hour": 10, "minute": 0} //shift ends
      },
      {
        "startTime": { "hour": 15, "minute": 0 },
        "endTime": { "hour": 23, "minute": 59 }
      }
    ],
    "Thursday": [
      {
        "startTime": { "hour": 0, "minute": 0 },
        "endTime": { "hour": 23, "minute": 59 }
      }
    ],
  }
```

I need to add a field to indicate if the place is open now or not,

```
{
 $addFields: {
  isOpenNow: {
      $and: [
    {
      $or: [
        {
          $lt: ['$openingTimes.Wednesday.startTime.hour', 14]
        },
        {
          $and: [
            {
              $lte: ['$openingTimes.Wednesday.startTime.hour', 14]
            },
            {
              $lte: ['$openingTimes.Wednesday.startTime.minute', 0]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      $or: [
        {
         $gt: ['$openingTimes.Wednesday.endTime.hour', 14]
        },
        {
          $and: [
            {
              $gte: ['$openingTimes.Wednesday.endTime.hour', 14]
            },
            {
             $gte: ['$openingTimes.Wednesday.endTime.minute', 0]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
  }
```

but it ends up with a result of false I think `$gte: ['$openingTimes.Wednesday.endTime.hour', 14]` compares the array of hours to 14, is there is a way to indicate if the place is open based on it's shifts.

Comment: The data would seem to indicate that it is closed at 14:00 on Wednesday.  There is shift that ends at 10:00, and the next starts at 15:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below aggregate:

```
{
  isPlaceOPen: {
    $cond: {
          if: { $gt: [{ $size: {
      $filter: {
        input: '$openingTimes.Wednesday',
        as: 'shift',
        cond: {
          $and: [
            {
              $or: [
                {
                  $lt: [
                    '$$shift.startTime.hour',
                    14
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $lte: [
                        '$$shift.startTime.hour',
                        14
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $lte: [
                        '$$shift.startTime.minute',
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              $or: [
                {
                  $gt: [
                    '$$shift.endTime.hour',
                    14
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $and: [
                    {
                      $gte: [
                        '$$shift.endTime.hour',
                        14
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      $gte: [
                        '$$shift.endTime.minute',
                        0
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    } }, 0] },
          then: true,
          else: false,
        },
  }
}
```